# Rebuild StreamBuilder based on internet connectivity

Tags: flutter

In my app, StreamBuilder is using for firebase and provider for connectivity.

Background:

I switched on the internet and streambuilder loads the images from firebase for 5 lists. Now, I switched off the internet and scrolled up, the images are not loaded and showing placeholder image for the next lists. I think it is correct because of streambuilder loads only for the visible screen. As the images from firebase are not available, the placeholder is considered an ImageStream.

Query:

I want to change/update the placeholder with images when I switch on the internet. Now, snapshot from firebase is the same and placeholder is considered as imagestream, I don't see images from firebase in lists.

With internet connectivity as a provider, I can build the streambuilder but the snapshot is the same, I don't know how to update.

Answer (score 0):

This a possible solution for the issue you proposed. It is using a listener instead of a `StreamBuilder` for your list and re-listen to your `Stream` whenever your internet connection is restored by using the [connectivity package](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) to listen to connection changes. Since you didn't provide any code, here is an example:

**Imports**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
```

**Declarations & Methods**

```
StreamSubscription subscription;
List<String> myStrings = [];

@override
void initState() {
  subscription = new Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((
    ConnectivityResult result) {
      handleConnectivityChange(result);
    }
  );
  listenToStringList();
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  subscription.cancel();
  myStreamFromStateOrParentWidget.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}

void listenToStringList(){
  myStreamFromStateOrParentWidget.listen((snapshot){
    setState(() {
      myStrings = snapshot;
    });
  });
}

void handleConnectivityChange(connectionState){
  debugPrint('connectionState: $connectionState');
  switch(connectionState) {
    case ConnectivityResult.none:
      debugPrint('no connection');
      break;

    case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
      listenToStringList();
      break;

    case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
      listenToStringList();
      break;

    default:
      debugPrint('default');
      break;
  }
}
```

**Widgets**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: myStrings.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Text(myStrings[index]);
        }
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: why sometims not working ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67260823/check-network-in-flutter